# How can I start the "Emojy & Symbols" app with a Keyboard Shortcut?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a MacBook Pro with Catalina 10.15.6. I need to start the "Emoji & Symbols" app (which is available in the Mac Menu Bar) with a Keyboard Shortcut:

[image]

[image]

So I showed the Keyboard Shortcuts settings in System Settings:

[image]

But in the menu of available programs I did not find the "Emojy & Symbols" app:

[image]

So how can I start the "Emoji & Symbols" app with a Keyboard Shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already built-in to the system.

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Space</kbd>

It doesn't have its own pref or on/off toggle, but you can override the default key command by calling it as a Menu Item for All Apps, rather than as an App itself.

<sup>Copied from my own answer at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230382/changing-emoji-shortcut)</sup>
This will work everywhere that Emoji & Symbols has a menu item - this doesn't modify the keyboard menu bar, it works inside an app with the commend.

- System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
- Click 'All Applications'
  <sub>(hidden in the picture)</sub>
- Click +
- Type Emoji & Symbols in the first box  <sup>[1]</sup>
- Type your replacement trigger in the second
- Click Add

[image]

This is the menu item the command override will affect…

[image]
<sup>[1]</sup> or, of course, the equivalent in any non-English language OS.

Comment: Thank you very much! Why this important information about the BUILT-IN keyboard shortcut is not displayed somewhere?

Comment: They're documented - but there are **so** many default key commands in macOS it's hard to keep track. https://support.apple.com/HT201236

Comment: You can find the default in any app that has this as a menu item - you are not modifying the separate Keyboard menu bar item, btw - I've added another pic & some further explanation.

Comment: doesn't work, unfortunately

Comment: @Bowen - it's worked for a decade. If you have evidence it's broken in a more recent OS, details would help. Or better still, raise it as a new question, with reference link back to this one, explaining what may have changed or been broken in recent versions. Confirmed still working in Ventura, don't have access to Sonoma yet.